# How to fix unwanted new line in java?

Tags: java, methods, return

I am trying to figure why my code is creating a new line every time a return method called is within a for-loop. The if statement within the main for-loop checks every Student Object inside the array list named list. After it is done comparing Student i to Student j (Student j being the second for-loop). Once Student i have found the best match, it is supposed to print out a statement saying either he/she has matched with someone.

Here is ***what it is supposed*** to return:

```
Abey matches with Melissa with score 60
John matches with Jeff with score 100
Craig has no matches.
```

***Instead***, it returns this:

```
Abey matches with 
Melissa with score 60

John matches with 
Jeff with score 100

Craig has no matches.
```

Here is the code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    int maxScore = 0;
    int currentScore = 0;
    int bestMatchScore = 0;
    int bestMatchStudent = 0;
    if (!list.get(i).isMatched()) {
        for (int j = i; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (!list.get(j).isMatched()) {
                if (j != i) {
                currentScore = list.get(i).compare(list.get(j));
                if (currentScore > maxScore) {
                    maxScore = currentScore;
                    bestMatchStudent = j;
                    bestMatchScore = maxScore;
                }
                }
            }
        }
            if(bestMatchScore == 0) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i).getName() + " has no matches.");
                }
            else {
                list.get(i).setMatched(list.get(bestMatchStudent));

                System.out.println(list.get(i).getName() + " matches with " + list.get(bestMatchStudent).getName() + " with score " + maxScore);
            }
        }
    }
```

If I were to remove all of the getName() inside the if-else statement, I get an output that is sort of what I desire:

```
Student@6d3552ed matches with Student@47d77d9e with score 60
Student@147834eb matches with Student@5fda3acc with score 100
Student@704a583d has no matches.
```

I suspect that it has to do something with calling the getName method. All it is is an accessor method...

Here is all the code to reproduce the problem:

***Student Class***

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private char gender;
    private Date birthdate;
    private Preference pref;
    private boolean matched;

public Student(String name, char gender, Date birthdate, Preference pref) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.birthdate = birthdate;
    this.pref = pref;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public char getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public Date getBirthdate() {
    return birthdate;
}

public Preference getPref() {
    return pref;
}

public boolean isMatched() {
    return matched;
}

public void setMatched() {
    this.matched = true;
}

public void setMatched(Student roommate) {
    setMatched();
    roommate.setMatched();
}

public int compare(Student st) {
    if (st.getGender() != gender)
        return 0;       
    return Math.abs((40 - pref.compare(st.getPref())) + (60 - birthdate.compare(st.getBirthdate())));
}

}
```

***Match Class***

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class Match {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //Student[] fullRoster = new Student[5]; converted to ArrayList
    ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    String fileName = "Students.txt";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
    input.useDelimiter("[\t\r-]");
    //int studentIndex = 0; converted to ArrayList
    while(input.hasNext()) {
        String name = input.next();
        //System.out.println(name);
        char gender = input.next().charAt(0);
        //System.out.println(gender);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        //System.out.println(month);
        int day = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        //System.out.println(day);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        //System.out.println(year);
        Date birthday = new Date(year, month, day);
        //System.out.println(birthday); //Printed out birthday
        int pref1 = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        //System.out.println(pref1);
        int pref2 = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        //System.out.println(pref2);
        int pref3 = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        //System.out.println(pref3);
        int pref4 = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        //System.out.println(pref4);
        Preference pref = new Preference(pref1, pref2, pref3, pref4);
        //System.out.println(pref); //Printed out pref
        //fullRoster[studentIndex] = new Student(name, gender, birthday, pref); converted to ArrayList
        list.add(new Student(name, gender, birthday, pref));
        //studentIndex++; converted to ArrayList                
    }

    input.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    int maxScore = 0;
    int currentScore = 0;
    int bestMatchScore = 0;
    int bestMatchStudent = 0;
    if (!list.get(i).isMatched()) {
        for (int j = i; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (!list.get(j).isMatched()) {
                if (j != i) {
                currentScore = list.get(i).compare(list.get(j));
                if (currentScore > maxScore) {
                    maxScore = currentScore;
                    bestMatchStudent = j;
                    bestMatchScore = maxScore;
                }
                }
            }
        }
            if(bestMatchScore == 0) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i) + " has no matches.");
                }
            else {
                list.get(i).setMatched(list.get(bestMatchStudent));

                System.out.println(list.get(i).getName() + " matches with " + list.get(bestMatchStudent) + " with score " + maxScore);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

***Preference Class***

```
public class Preference {
private int quietTime, music, reading, chatting;

public Preference(int quietTime, int music, int reading, int chatting) {
    this.quietTime = quietTime;
    this.music = music;
    this.reading = reading;
    this.chatting = chatting;
}

public int getQuietTime() {
    return quietTime;
}

public int getMusic() {
    return music;
}

public int getReading() {
    return reading;
}

public int getChatting() {
    return chatting;
}

public int compare(Preference pref) {
    int difference = 0;
    difference += Math.abs(pref.getQuietTime() - this.getQuietTime());
    difference += Math.abs(pref.getMusic() - this.getMusic());
    difference += Math.abs(pref.getReading() - this.getReading());
    difference += Math.abs(pref.getChatting() - this.getChatting());
    return difference;
}

}
```

***Date Class***

```
public class Date {
int year, month, day;

public Date(int year, int month, int day) {
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public int getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public int getDay() {
    return day;
}

public int compare(Date dt) {
    int yearsDifferenceInDays = (Math.abs(year - dt.getYear())) * 365;
    int daysDifference = Math.abs(dt.dayOfYear() - this.dayOfYear());
    int totalDifference = Math.abs(yearsDifferenceInDays - daysDifference);
    int monthsDifference = totalDifference / 30;
    if(monthsDifference > 60)
        return 60;
    return monthsDifference;
}

public int dayOfYear() {
    int totalDays = 0;
    switch (month) {
    case 12: totalDays += 30;
    case 11: totalDays += 31;
    case 10: totalDays += 30;
    case 9 : totalDays += 31;
    case 8 : totalDays += 31;
    case 7 : totalDays += 30;
    case 6 : totalDays += 31;
    case 5 : totalDays += 30;
    case 4 : totalDays += 31;
    case 3 : totalDays += 28;
    case 2 : totalDays += 31;
    }
    totalDays += day;
    return totalDays;
    }
}
```

***Match Class***

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Match {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //Student[] fullRoster = new Student[5]; converted to ArrayList
    ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    String fileName = "Students.txt";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
    input.useDelimiter("[\t\r-]");
    //int studentIndex = 0; converted to ArrayList
    while(input.hasNext()) {
        String name = input.next();
        //System.out.println(name);
        char gender = input.next().charAt(0);
        //System.out.println(gender);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        //System.out.println(month);
        int day = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        //System.out.println(day);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        //System.out.println(year);
        Date birthday = new Date(year, month, day);
        //System.out.println(birthday); //Printed out birthday
        int pref1 = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        //System.out.println(pref1);
        int pref2 = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        //System.out.println(pref2);
        int pref3 = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        //System.out.println(pref3);
        int pref4 = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        //System.out.println(pref4);
        Preference pref = new Preference(pref1, pref2, pref3, pref4);
        //System.out.println(pref); //Printed out pref
        //fullRoster[studentIndex] = new Student(name, gender, birthday, pref); converted to ArrayList
        list.add(new Student(name, gender, birthday, pref));
        //studentIndex++; converted to ArrayList                
    }

    input.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    int maxScore = 0;
    int currentScore = 0;
    int bestMatchScore = 0;
    int bestMatchStudent = 0;
    if (!list.get(i).isMatched()) {
        for (int j = i; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (!list.get(j).isMatched()) {
                if (j != i) {
                currentScore = list.get(i).compare(list.get(j));
                if (currentScore > maxScore) {
                    maxScore = currentScore;
                    bestMatchStudent = j;
                    bestMatchScore = maxScore;
                }
                }
            }
        }
            if(bestMatchScore == 0) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i) + " has no matches.");
                }
            else {
                list.get(i).setMatched(list.get(bestMatchStudent));

                System.out.println(list.get(i).getName() + " matches with " + list.get(bestMatchStudent) + " with score " + maxScore);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

***Students.txt***

```
Abey    F   5-5-1996    0   0   0   0
John    M   5-5-1997    10  10  10  10
Melissa F   5-5-1996    10  10  10  10
Craig   M   5-5-1998    5   5   5   5
Jeff    M   5-5-1997    10  10  10  10
```

Comment: How do you read the data to fill `Student#name`?

Comment: Where's the code to enter names? Probably adding a newline at the start of the line ...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Try System.out.print instead of 'System.out.println'

Comment: It would *seem* that `getName()` includes a trailing newline, which you could get rid of with `trim()`, but then why isn't there another one after `Melissa `? Surely this isn't the real code?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I read the Student data off a file

Comment: I didn't read your above project (question) but you should divide your issue to small one, then it will be easy to solve.

Comment: @AntonH There is no code to enter names

Comment: @shmosel I just went ahead and pasted all the code so that it is replicable.

Comment: The debugger would aide you well with this issue. Probably quicker than us trying to combine all this code to figure out the problem ourselves without running it

Comment: @Nitin Dhomse I have before, and this was what I got
Abey matches with 
Melissa with score 60
John matches with 
Jeff with score 100
Craig has no matches.

Comment: Not quite "minimal", but we're getting somewhere.

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't know how to use Eclipse's debugger before. I mainly just debug by printing out.

Comment: Plenty of free resources available to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I were to remove all of the getName() inside the if-else statement, I get an output that is sort of what I desire:
>
> ```
> Student@6d3552ed matches with Student@47d77d9e with score 60
> Student@147834eb matches with Student@5fda3acc with score 100
> Student@704a583d has no matches.
> ```

That output is explained here [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Seems like you just need to `trim()` the name.

Depending on where you want your "input validation" to be oerformed, you could do that at input.

```
String name = input.next().trim();
```

Or in the constuctor

```
public Student(String name, char gender, Date birthdate, Preference pref) {
    this.name = name.trim();
    this.gender = gender;
    this.birthdate = birthdate;
    this.pref = pref;
}
```

Or in the getter

```
public String getName() {
    return name.trim();
}
```

Or when you actually display the value in the `println`

Or define `toString()`, as explained in the other post to `return name.trim();`, and just print `list.get(i)`, as you had done.

---

The root issue may be that you haven't defined LF (`\n`) or CRLF (`\r\n`) as a delimiter.

```
input.useDelimiter("[\t\r-]");
```

Try

```
input.useDelimiter("\r\n|[\t\r\n-]");
```

Comment: input.useDelimiter("\r\n|[\t\r\n-]"); solves the underlying problem. Can you explain the syntax you used? Why is \r\n| outside?

Comment: Because inside `[]` those aren't treated as consecutive elements. http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws?regex=%5Cr%5Cn%7C%5B%5Cr%5Ct-%5D&env=env_java

Answer (score 1):

I can give a solution to resolve this problem like:
 without printing whole at a time like:

```
System.out.println(list.get(i).getName() + " matches with " + list.get(bestMatchStudent).getName() + " with score " + maxScore);
```

do it as follows:

```
String name  = list.get(i).getName().trim();
String bestMachStudentName = list.get(bestMatchStudent).getName().trim();
if(!name .equals("") &&  !bestMachStudentName.equals("") ){
System.out.println( name  + " matches with " + bestMachStudentName  + " with score " + maxScore);
}
else{
// other stuff......
}
```

I don't know why this `println()` function is behaving like that it may be a possible problem in getting value from a list.

I hope it will work fine.

Comment: `isEmpty()` reads better than `.equals("")`. However, the problem is not empty strings.

Comment: It didn't work. It is weird cause it isn't being called within the println statement.